# How to check if a string is a cyclic rotation of another?

Tags: r, string, cyclic

How can one check if a given string is a cyclic rotation of another given string in R? Ex: `1234` is a cyclic rotation of `3412` by two shifts. But I'd like to check if a string is cyclically equivalent to another string or not, by any number of shifts whatsoever.

Comment: Not sure how robust it could be, but you could try replicating each vector and `grepl` the other, alternatively -- `grepl(y, strrep(x, 2)) || grepl(x, strrep(y, 2))`

Comment: @alexis_laz Nice! Wouldn't a check of `nchar` be sufficient for your first suggestion? `nchar(x) == nchar(y) & grepl(pattern = y, x = strrep(x, 2))`. Care to post an answer?

Answer (score 3):

Accomodating Henrik's comment, testing (i) for `nchar` equality and (ii) if one vector is part of the other after replicating the second, seems to be sufficient:

```
ff = function(x, y) (nchar(y) == nchar(x)) && (grepl(y, strrep(x, 2), fixed = TRUE))

ff("3412", "1234")
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: That's a good one! Duplicating the string is the key and letting the regex engine do all the work. Much better than creating all possible cyclic rotations on your own.

Comment: @UweBlock : I think the main drawback here, appears if "x" is very large and `strrep` cannot allocate the needed memory

Comment: Available memory might not be the first limit being reached.  `?"Memory-limits"` says _The number of bytes in a character string is limited to 2^31 - 1 ~ 2*10^9_. So, if `y` has the maximum length then `x` can only have half the bytes. In total, `x` and `y` may have a maximum of 3*10^9 bytes which roughly translates to 3 GB of memory. Perhaps, unicode may require more memory but available memory is probably not the show stopper for your approach.

Answer (score 2):

You can just generate successive rotations until you find a match. If none of the rotations match, then the strings are not cyclic rotations of one another. Solution using `sub`:

```
cycrotT = function(s1,s2) {
  if (nchar(s1)!=nchar(s2)) {
    return(FALSE) }
  for (i in 1:nchar(s2)) {
    if (s1==s2) {
      return(TRUE) }
    # Move the first character to the end of the string
    s2 = sub('(.)(.*)', '\\2\\1', s2)
  }
  return(FALSE)
}


> cycrotT("1234567", "1324567")
# [1] FALSE
> cycrotT("1234567", "4567123")
# [1] TRUE
> cycrotT("1234567", "1234568")
# [1] FALSE
```

Comment: Seems to pass all the tests so far but suffers from being code-only. Put in an explanation and it will be upvote-worthy.

Answer (score 1):

A longer, but perhaps clearer picture of a way to do this:

```
cyclic_index <- function(string1, string2) {

  ## gather info about the first string
  chars <- el(strsplit(string1, ""))
  length <- length(chars)
  vec <- seq_len(length)

  ## create a matrix of possible permutations
  permutations <- data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = length, ncol = length + 1))
  names(permutations) <- c("id", paste0("index", vec))

  permutations$id <- vec

  ## calculate the offset indices
  for (r in vec)
    permutations[r, vec + 1] <- (vec + r - 1) %% (length)

  ## a %% a = 0 so reset this to a
  permutations[permutations == 0] <- length

  ## change from indices to characters
  permutations[ , vec + 1] <- sapply(vec, function(x) chars[unlist(permutations[x, vec + 1])])

  ## paste the characters back into strings
  permutations$string <- sapply(vec, function(x) paste0(permutations[x , vec + 1], collapse = ''))

  ## if string2 is a permutation of string1, return TRUE
  return(string2 %in% permutations$string)

}

cyclic_index("jonocarroll", "carrolljono")
#> TRUE

cyclic_index("jonocarroll", "callorrjono")
#> FALSE

cyclic_index("1234567", "4567123")
#> TRUE
```